# Обработка последовательности файлов

Tags: excel, vba

Не могу понять почему ошибка?

Скрин 1 - при открытых тектовых файлах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин 2 - после закрытия текстовых файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Листинг:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BatchProcess()
    Dim FileSpec As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileList() As String
    Dim FoundFiles As Integer

'   Указание пути и спецификаций файла
    FileSpec = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "text??.txt"
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)

'   Найден ли файл?
    If FileName <> "" Then
        FoundFiles = 1
        ReDim Preserve FileList(1 To FoundFiles)
        FileList(FoundFiles) = FileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Не найдены файлы, которые соответствуют " & FileSpec
        Exit Sub
    End If

'   Получение других имен файлов
    Do
        FileName = Dir
        If FileName = "" Then Exit Do
        FoundFiles = FoundFiles + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileList(1 To FoundFiles)
        FileList(FoundFiles) = FileName & "*"
    Loop

'   Циклический обход и обработка файлов
    For i = 1 To FoundFiles
        Call ProcessFiles(FileList(i))
    Next i
End Sub


Sub ProcessFiles(FileName As String)
'   Импорт файла
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=FileName, _
        Origin:=xlWindows, _
        StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(0, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(12, 1))
'   Ввод суммарных формул
    Range("D1").Value = "A"
    Range("D2").Value = "B"
    Range("D3").Value = "C"
    Range("E1:E3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(B:B,D1)"
    Range("F1:F3").Formula = "=SUMIF(B:B,D1,C:C)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Эксель не может открыть два файла с одинаковыми именами. Или сделайте так чтобы имена разные были или открывайте по одному файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В процедуру `Sub ProcessFiles(FileName As String)`передается "чистое" имя файла, без указания пути. Понятно, попытка открыть файл из ниоткуда приводит к ошибке.

Или передавать полный путь с именем:

```
Call ProcessFiles(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileList(i))
```

или добавить путь в исполняемой процедуре:

```
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName, _...
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! с Обеими вариантами работает.